# Google API: Get list of person's meetings

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to schedule a meeting through Google API, but it would be nice to know an individual's availability before creating the meeting. Is there a way to get a list of a person's current meetings so that I can offer suggestions on when to schedule the new meeting?

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of events on users calendar, you should do one of the following:

1. Users calendar should be public or
2. You should have service account, where you are the admin. Initially users should share their calendar with you. Also, service account that you created needs to be granted access to the Google Apps domain’s user data that you want to access. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) for additional information.

To get the events list on Google calendar, you can use [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) by giving the calendar id of the calendar you want to retrieve in the request.